# Query to get all Cosmos DB documents referenced by another

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Assume I have the following Cosmos DB container with the possible doc type partitions:

```
{
  "id": <string>,
  "partitionKey": <string>, // Always "item"
  "name": <string>
}
```

```
{
  "id": <string>,
  "partitionKey": <string>, // Always "group"
  "items": <array[string]>  // Always an array of ids for items in the "item" partition
}
```

I have the id of a "group" document, but I do not have the document itself. What I would like to do is perform a query which gives me all "item" documents referenced by the "group" document.

I know I can perform two queries: 1) Retrieve the "group" document, 2) Perform a query with IN clause on the "item" partition.

As I don't care about the "group" document other than getting the list of ids, is it possible to construct a single query to get me all the "item" documents I want with just the "group" document id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to perform two queries, as there are no joins between separate documents. Even though there is support for subqueries, only *correlated* subqueries are currently supported (meaning, the inner subquery is referencing values from the outer query). Non-correlated subqueries are what you'd need.

Note that, even though you don't want all of the `group` document, you don't need to retrieve the entire document. You can project just the `items` property, which can then be used in your 2nd query, with something like `array_contains()`. Something like:

```sql
SELECT VALUE g.items
FROM g
WHERE g.id="1"
AND g.partitionKey="group"

SELECT VALUE i.name
FROM i
WHERE array_contains(<items-from-prior-query>,i.id)
AND i.partitionKey="item"
```

This [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery#types-of-subqueries) clarifies the two subquery types and support for only correlated subqueries.