# How do I perform a subquery in cosmosdb where statement?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to cosmosdb so bear with me. Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a document that has an array value. Here's the query

`select value c.NodeIds from c where c.PartitionKey = 'contentlink' and c.id = '123'`

I want to use this result in my where statement, but I'm having trouble understanding how to do this. Here's what I tried to come up with.

```
SELECT c.*

FROM c 

where c.PartitionKey = 'node' 

and c.id in (select value n from n in c.NodeIds where c.PartitionKey = 'contentlink' and c.id = '123')
```

Comment: What you're attempting to do looks like a *non-correlated subquery* (grabbing results of one query to feed a parameter into another, separate query). Only *correlated* subqueries are supported, so you'd need to do two queries. Please look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65745201/272109) on another question which appears to be very similar (possibly a duplicate of yours).